# Unable to program Arduino mega2560?

Tags: arduino-mega

I am using arduino mega for my application .  Board works well for a week , from yesterday it  is not programming at all , it shows me some error like timeout . What could be the problem kindly  help me to solve this.

```
avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Dec 16 2016 at 13:33:19
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM20
         Using Programmer              : wiring
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM20": The system cannot find the file specified.


Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
avrdude: ser_drain(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Comment: `avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM20": The system cannot find the file specified.` -- There's a hint right there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com 20 is not configured with your arduino. Go to the arduino program and I think it is on the tools tab or the one next to it. There should be a port label and it says which com port to use. Then go to device manager, then ports. Then go to properties on the port that has arduino and change that to the port the arduino program said. It should work then. This topic has been solved many times.

Comment: ya its working fine now...

Comment: I am glad to hear that.

Comment: But this problem occurs very often why?.... Now also i am getting this error what could be the problem...